# PHP: Get unique ID inside Docker container

Tags: php, docker, mqtt, uniqueidentifier

To register with a MQTT service I need a unique client ID inside a Docker container. Does the [PHP function uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.uniqid.php) work for that?

```
$uniqueId = uniqid();
```

Or is it better to combine this with the Docker container ID?
What is PHP oneliner code for that?

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens? One thing to keep in mind: `uniqid` will generate a new ID on each call - so if you want to have an enduring ID, you either have to store it somewhere or use something else

Comment: Good point: I need to have an enduring ID in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
 uniqid ([ string $prefix = "" [, bool $more_entropy = FALSE ]] ) : string
```

> Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in
>   microseconds.

**Caution**

> This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and
>   should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a
>   cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(),
>   random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

If you are using

```
$id = uniqid (null, true);
```

You should be totally fine.